# Ensure UITextField stays onscreen despite scrolling

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitextfield

How can I ensure that a UITextField stays on screen despite not currently viewing the bottom of a UITableView? Like when I scroll up, how can it stay on-screen rather than disappear at the bottom of the screen. I want it anchored to the bottom of the screen at all times.

Edit: It does not appear when I add it as a subview.

2ndEdit: Stop docking post please..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add it to view that contains `tableView` i.e `tableView` superView.if your viewController has tableView.You can do like

```
    self.view.addSubView(yourTextFied)
    self.view.bringSubviewToFront(yourTextFied)
```

and set the frame of `yourTextField` approprately

Comment: This does not work, in fact it does not appear at all. I added a UIView the same way and it does, this UITextField however is not.

Comment: Ok amazingly it is appearing, however it graphically glitches to ensure that everything except the indicator is invisible. Is this an Xcode 6 glitch?

Comment: Have you set the frame of textField appropriate? and please set background of you textField.It should be there         myView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()

Comment: yes it is absolutely correct.Set the backgroundColor of textField.

Comment: I fixed it, turns out textField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.RoundedRect must be set first otherwise it is not visible (defaults to .None)

Comment: yes by default it is set to `UITextBorderStyle.None`

Comment: So how can I anchor it? Use ScrollView delegate to adjust the y value?

Comment: what do you mean by `anchor`

Comment: Have it stay onscreen rather than scroll with other contents within the scroll view. I have it placed in a tableview which inherits UIScrollView.

Comment: You have to place it on tableVeiw superView so it will not scroll.

Comment: is your controller is `UITableViewController` or `UIViewController`

Comment: I get Optional.None error basically meaning the superview is nil.

Comment: It is UITableViewController

Comment: I guess I could have ViewController and embed a UITableViewController in that using a container? Would be a bit messy.

Comment: OHoo so `UITableViewController` view is `tableView` by `self.view.addSubView(yourTextFied)` means you are adding it to `tableView`.

Comment: No you just need to have `UIViewController` and add `tableView` as subView from interfaceBuilder and set its delegate and dataSource.and than add these two line given in answer

Comment: self.view is self.tableView so yes.